# The argument type 'void Function(bool?, int) Function(bool?, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(bool?)?'

Tags: flutter, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to learn Flutter and I'm developing Todo app
But I got stuck with a bug
Here is my code

List view

```
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Todo(
                taskName: todos[index][0],
                completed: todos[index][1],
                onChanged: (value, index) => checkboxChanged); // here the index argument is causing the error
          },
        )
```

and the Todo class

```
class Todo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String taskName;
  final bool completed;

  Function(bool?)? onChanged; // the method 

  Todo(
      {super.key,
      required this.taskName,
      required this.completed,
      required this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, right: 10),
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellow, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: completed,
                onChanged: onChanged,
                activeColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              Text(taskName),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

There comes up when I add the index parameter here

```
  void checkboxChanged(bool? value, int index) { // if I remove the indext parameter from here and from the Todo instantiation in the ListView the error will be gone. but I need that way
    setState(() {
      todos[index][1] = !todos[index][1];
    });
  }
```

The error message I'm facing is

```
The argument type 'void Function(bool?, int) Function(bool?, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(bool?)?'
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks...

Comment: You are passing a function that requires two arguments where a function that expects only one argument is expected.  You instead should pass a function that adapts one to the other.  You can do that by changing `onChanged: (value, index) => checkboxChanged)` to `onChanged: (value) => checkboxChanged(value, index)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `onChanged` of your widget-class `Todo` is defined as:

```dart
Function(bool?)? onChanged
```

- **Function** indicates the field `onChanged` is a function. In Dart everything is an object, event functions.
- The **?** at the end indicates the field can be `null`
- Since the return type of the function is omitted it has the implicit return of "void".
- **(bool?)** indicates this function takes one argument which is a boolean or null.

However in your constructor of the instance of *Todo* in the *ListView* you are passing `(value, index) => checkboxChanged` which is a function that takes two arguments, 1) `value` and 2) `index`, and returns another function `checkboxChanged` (again, since everything is an object you can return a function as the result from another function).

To fix this you shall comply to what Todo is expected in the argument `onChanged`:

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Todo(
                taskName: todos[index][0],
                completed: todos[index][1],
                onChanged: (value) => checkboxChanged(value, index),
             );
          },
        )
```

This is equivalent to passing to `onChanged` an unnamed function which takes the "value" object and within that function it calls `checkboxChanged` with that value and the index provided by the builder of *ListView*.

```dart
onChanged: (value) {
  checkboxChanged(value, index);
}
```